# Getting list from viewmodel in observe event -MVVM

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

I have a issue in getting a list returned in observe event in my activity. i am developing a login screen in MVVM. viewmodel is as follows.

my problem is i can get returned data in observe call back into a UI control. but same data returned assign into a list variable is empty. in other words, list returned unable to pass into a a list variable in an activity.

```
class LoginViewModel @Inject internal constructor (private val loginRepository: LoginRepository,private val usersRepository: UsersRepository): ViewModel() {

    private var _userEmail:MutableLiveData<String>
    private var _userPassword:MutableLiveData<String>
    private var _userLoginData:MutableLiveData<UserLoginData>
    private var allUsers:MutableLiveData<List<Users>>
    private var findUser:MutableLiveData<List<Users>>

    init{
        _userEmail= MutableLiveData()
        _userPassword= MutableLiveData()
        _userLoginData= MutableLiveData()
        allUsers= MutableLiveData()
        findUser= MutableLiveData()
    }


    fun getEmail():LiveData<String>{
        return _userEmail
    }

    fun getPassword():MutableLiveData<String>{
        return _userPassword
    }

    fun userLogin(userEmail:String,userPassword:String):MutableLiveData<UserLoginData>{
        _userEmail.postValue(userEmail)
        _userPassword.postValue(userPassword)


        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var userlogindata:UserLoginData=loginRepository.userLogin(userEmail,userPassword)
            _userLoginData.postValue(userlogindata)
        }

        return _userLoginData
    }


    fun getAllUsers():MutableLiveData<List<Users>>{
        //lateinit var _allUsers:List<Users>

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val _allUsers:List<Users> =usersRepository.getUsers()
            allUsers.postValue(_allUsers)
        }

        return allUsers
    }

    fun findUser(userEmail:String):MutableLiveData<List<Users>>{
        //lateinit var finduser:List<Users>

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val _findUser:List<Users> =usersRepository.findUser(userEmail)
            findUser.postValue(_findUser)
        }

        return findUser
    }
}
```

in an activity i am observing the users list and getting the list into a list variable in the activity. code in the activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    lateinit var loginData:UserLoginData
    var users:List<Users> = emptyList()
    var findUser:List<Users> = emptyList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        loginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)


        /*observe users list*/
        loginViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, {It->
            users=It

            binding.textView.text=It[0].email.toString()

        })

        loginViewModel.findUser(binding.loginEditTextTextEmailAddressTxt.toString().trim()).observe(this,{it->
            findUser=it
        })
```

This program failed if i use data in the users or findUser lists.

Kindly help me to find the best practice in getting the changed data from viewmodel into an activity

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel:

```
data class User(
    var name: String
)

private val _allUsers = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()
private val allUsers: LiveData<List<User>> get() = _allUsers

fun fetchAllUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        //delay is simulating network request delay
        delay(1000)
        //listOf is simulating usersRepository.getUsers()
        _allUsers.value = listOf(User("name1"), User("name2"), User("name3"))
    }
    return allUsers
}
```

Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.fetchAllUsers().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { userList ->
        userList.forEach {
            Log.d("user", it.name)
        }
}
```

You can try this way but I do not prefer returning liveData with function because you have to observe liveData once. You need to be careful observe once.

Comment: Observing livedata and bind it into a UI view is working fine in my code. the problem in my code was when i assign the List<Users> into a list variable loginViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, {It->
            users=It

            binding.textView.text=It[0].email.toString()

        })   users list variable is still become empty. but value passed into It lambda parameter having a value which means list is not empty. but i cant use that passed list because assigned variable is becoming empty